# Adding deserialize interface to model causes error

Tags: angular

Still new to TypeScript and Modeling but I'm getting an error when I add a deserializable interface to my Models. Here's my mock json data:

```
{
  "isAdmin": true,
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "Person 1",
      "userId": 123
    },
    {
      "name": "Person 2",
      "userId": 456
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my two models:

```
export class PersonProfile implements Deserializable {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  people: People[];

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);

    this.people = input.people.map((person) =>
      new Person().deserialize(person)
    );

    return this;
  }
}
```

And here's the *Person* Model:

```
export class Person implements Deserializable {
  name: string;
  userId?: number;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    return Object.assign(this, input);
  }
}
```

And the *Deserializable* interface:

```
export interface Deserializable {
  deserialize(input: any): this;
}
```

The service is pretty simple:

```
export class PersonService {
  public person: Person;

  constructor() {}

  getPerson(): Person {
    return person;
  }
}
```

And my component calls it like this:

```
person: PersonProfile;

ngOnInit() {
    this.person = this.personService.getPerson();
    this.createForm(); // builds a dynamic form
  }
```

This is the error:

```
Property 'deserialize' is missing in type Person
```

Doesn't this mean that my data really isn't modeled correctly? If I inspect the response this is what I see, straight JSON:

Naturally, if I remove the *deserialize* method then everything works just fine. So, what is happening? Did I mess up the modeling? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution for the Error

It looks like the error is in your **service**

```js
import profile from '../../../shared/utils/client-profile.json';
import { ClientProfile } from '../models/client-profile.model';

export class ClientProfileService {
  public profile: ClientProfile;

  constructor() {}

  getClientProfile(): ClientProfile {
    return profile; // <- this is the profile you loaded from the .json file 
    // so it does not have `.deserialize()` which is where the error is coming from
  }
}
```

If you want to return the service's profile, you need `this.profile`, but it looks like you would need to map to that object first so you don't get a runtime error.

```js
import profile from '../../../shared/utils/client-profile.json';
import { ClientProfile } from '../models/client-profile.model';

export class ClientProfileService {
  public profile: ClientProfile;

  constructor() {
    // create a new ClientProfile from the loaded .json file
    // JSON.parse() may not be necessary
    this.profile = new ClientProfile().deserialize(JSON.parse(profile));
  }

  getClientProfile(): ClientProfile {
    return this.profile; // <- change to `this.profile`
  }
}
```

That should work (or at least get you closer).

### Modeling Practices

When it comes to modeling in Typescript the best solution (IMO) is to use `interfaces` to define your "POJO"s (Plain Old JavaScript Objects). The reason being, when you load data from a backend, your http client will convert the response to a JavaScript object behind the scenes. 
It will also prevent you from having to worry about constructing `new` classes all over the place.

For your particular scenario, I would implement the change like this:

**example folder structure** *(NOTE: I like to keep my services in a separate folder since they are usually provided in `root`)*

```
.
├── src
└── app
    ├── ...
    ├── services
    │   └── client-profile.service.ts
    ├── client-profile
    │   ├── client-profile.component.html
    │   └── client-profile.component.ts
    └── models
        └── client-profile.model.ts
```

**client-profile.model.ts**

```js
/* I like to prefix my interface delcarations with an `I` */
export interface IClientProfile {
  isPayrollAdmin: boolean;
  contacts: IContact[];
}

export interface IContact {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  phoneExt: number;
  email: string;
  implementationRole: boolean;
  operationsRole: boolean;
  userId: number;
}
```

Then you just tell typescript what type of object you expect to have and it will use your definition. So in your `client-profile.service.ts`, you won't need to construct a new class.

**client-profile.service.ts**

```js
import profile from '../../../shared/utils/client-profile.json';
import { IClientProfile } from '../models/client-profile.model';

export class ClientProfileService {
  public profile: IClientProfile;

  constructor() {
    // you don't need to create a new object because you already have a JavaScript object
    // you just need to tell typescript what kind of object you have
    this.profile = JSON.parse(profile) as IClientProfile;
  }

  getClientProfile(): IClientProfile {
    return this.profile; 
  }
}
```

When you get around to making http requests for data, you won't have to do any extra mapping to construct additional objects.

**client-profile.service.ts** *example http implementation*

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import profile from '../../../shared/utils/client-profile.json';
import { IClientProfile } from '../models/client-profile.model';

export class ClientProfileService {
  public profile: IClientProfile;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { /* ... */ }

  /** example http request where you tell typescript what kind of object you are expecting */
  loadAllProfiles(): Observable<IClientProfile[]> {
    return this.http.get<IClientProfile[]>('api/profiles');
  }

  // ... 
}
```

Try to avoid constructing or adding methods to data that you receive from the backend. You want to keep your data models as pure as possible.

Comment: This is how little I know about modeling. it makes sense that by calling deserialize() that is what converts the JSON to the Model -- is that true? However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you update your `getClientProfile()` method to return `this.profile`? Just curious what benefit you are getting by modeling your data to a `Deserializable` base class? Based on the `deserialize()` function, it doesn't look like you need it (but if you have future plans to add more logic to that function, then it could be useful). I can give some more feedback once I get your response.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you may need to call `JSON.parse(profile)` since you are loading a raw json file. Maybe try this: `this.profile = new ClientProfile().deserialize(JSON.parse(profile));` I'll update my answer

Comment: Excuse me, @DJ House - you are correct. I added the deserialize method but forgot to add this.profile. It's working now. And I'm new to Angular and added a Deserializable class because I thought that's how it's done in Angular 8.  All models need to be deserialized because it specifies the way the data from the API is mapped into our model classes.

Comment: Perfect. I'll update my answer with some additional feedback about modeling.

Comment: Updated my answer with the modeling. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome answer - learned a ton! Thank you so much for being so thorough.